# Are ubuntu snap servers only accessible via ipv4-only?

Tags: server, snap, repository, ipv6, ipv4

I tried to `apt update` and `snap refresh` on an IPv6-only Ubuntu machine. The update worked fine, but the snap refresh hasn't. The shown error only mentions that it timed out.

I tried three different machines, rebooted and reinstalled a few times, but the problem persists.

Could it be that the snap repositories are IPv4-only?

That's the only reason that comes to my mind, although I can't believe that there still could be publicly facing IPv4-only servers in 2023.

Comment: Read https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/ipv6-support/34842/2 - there *are* plans to support it, but snapcraft's store, etc. do not currently have IPv6 support

Comment: @ThomasWard thank you very much!